# Inverse of the composition of two functions

Tags: inverse, closed-form, function-and-relation-composition

If I have a composition of two functions:

$$y = f(g(x),h(x))$$

where both $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are readily invertible, can I find the inverse of the composition? i.e.: Can I find $x = f^{-1}(y)$? I know this is generally possible for the the composition of one function.

Perhaps there is a special form of f that permits this?

Thanks

Comment: "[Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)" is usually used to refer to $f\circ g$, the function $f\circ g(x):=f(g(x))$. You seem to be talking about something pretty different. If you mean $f\circ g$, the answer below should answer you. If you mean what you have written, you would not find $x=f^{-1}(y)$, but rather $(g(x),h(x))=f^{-1}(y)$, and I expect it not to be possible to get $x$ out of that.

Comment: Well, that all depends on what you take as the codomain of $(g(x),h(x))$. If you restrict it, then you will have $x=f^{-1}(g^{-1}(y))$. Naturally that all assumes $f$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and please forgive my notation; ideally what I would like is $x$ as a function of $y$ which, as in the example below, may include the inverses of $f$, $g$, and/or $h$.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Previous answer used the accepted definition of 'composition'. I am trying to interpret what the OP means by composition... I think he means that $f$ is a formula e.g. something like $f(\sin x,e^x)=\sin x\sqrt{e^x}$ means that $f(x,y)=x\sqrt{y}$.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be invertible maps.

Define a function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

$$y=F(x)=f(g(x),h(x)).$$

Then $F$ is invertible with

$$x=F^{-1}(y)=g^{-1}\left(\pi_1\left(f^{-1}(y)\right)\right)=h^{-1}\left(\pi_2\left(f^{-1}(y)\right)\right),$$

where $\pi_i:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the projection onto the $i$-th factor of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thank you but no this is not what I mean. Please see the comment above.

Comment: @user3448295 is this more what you are looking for? $f$ invertible is sufficient for $F$ invertible.

Answer (score 0):

An answer for the general case is given by the previous answer.

We write

$$F(x)=f(g(x),h(x)).$$

**a)**

Let's consider the case that your function $f$ is an algebraic function. We write $A=f$.
We presuppose $g,h$ are invertible functions over an open domain. We denote their inverses by $g^{-1}$ and $h^{-1}$ respectively.

Let's investigate the equation

$$A(g(x),h(x))=y,\tag{1}$$

where $g(x),h(x)$ are expressions and $A(g(x),h(x))$ is an algebraic expression in dependence of both $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ at the same time. So $A$ is an algebraic function with $A\colon D\subseteq\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}$. According to the invariance of dimension, $A$ is not injective and therefore not invertible.

But if the functions $g,h$ are algebraically dependent, an algebraic function $A_0$ exists so that $h(x)=A_0(g(x))$. Equation (1) then becomes

$$A(g(x),A_0(g(x)))=y.$$

Because the composition of algebraic functions is an algebraic function, an algebraic function $A_1$ then exists so that

$$A_1(g(x))=y.$$

If $A_1$ is bijective, we get

$$x=g^{-1}(A_1^{-1}(y)).$$

The main theorem in [Ritt 1925] that is also proved in [Risch 1979] applies this situation for the [Elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).
The [Elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) (according to Liouville and Ritt) are those functions which are obtained in a finite number of steps by performing algebraic operations and taking exponentials and logarithms. If your functions $f$, $g$ and $h$ are elementary functions, a result of the main theorem in [Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/) is: your elementary function $F$ can have an inverse that is an elementary function only if there exists an exp/ln-composition representation of $F$ whose member functions are all 1-ary functions.

Because each function is composed of bijective pieces, the problem can be applied to [partial inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses).

**b)**

If an existing inverse function is accepted, depends on the set of functions you allow. Take e.g.

$$F(x)=f(g(x),h(x))=x\cdot e^x.$$

We have:
$F\colon x\mapsto x\cdot e^x$,
$f\colon (x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_1\cdot x_2$,
$g\colon x\mapsto x$,
$h\colon x\mapsto e^x$ and
$F^{-1}\colon x\mapsto \textrm{LambertW}(x)$.
LambertW is a known funtion, but it's not an elementary function.
$\ $

[[Risch 1979] Risch, R. H.: Algebraic Properties of the Elementary Functions of Analysis. Amer. J. Math. 101 (1979) (4) 743-759](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373917?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

[[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/)